# Поробки, саморобки чи рукотвори?

Tags: вибір-слова, калька, існування-слова

Результати дитячої творчості (малюнки, витинанки, аплікації і т.і.) узагальнено в україномовному середовищі наразі називаються "поробками", але цього слова в жодному зі словників на r2u не знаходжу. Це новотвір чи калька? Чи правильно почати казати "рукотвори" чи "саморобки" замість поробки?

Comment: Див. також [«Як перекласти з російської слово „поделка“?»](/q/5767) (хоча там не конкретно про результати дитячої творчості, а радше шукають слово, щоб наголосити на низькій якості зробленого).

Answer (score 2):

Ось перші трапляння кожного слова, що я знайшов (у «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» і Google Книгах):

- Поробка — 1957:

  > Карпо ще майстрував різні дрібні поробки для базару: люльки, ложки, качалки, макогони, дзиги, фуркала, свищики, сопілки.
  > <sub>// Андрій Химко, «У пазурах вампіра. I. Шляхами до прийднів», 1957.</sub>
- Саморобка — <s>1961</s> <s>1925</s> 1909:

  > Біля станка валялись обкоровані осикові полінця і лежало кілька пачок зв'язаної стружки, що напрочуд пахла свіжою рибою. — Розглядаєш мою саморобку? — обізвався позаду Зіновій Петрович.
  > <sub>// Михайло Стельмах, «Правда і кривда», 1961.</sub>

  > Найперше для чого треба воску, це свічки виробляти: наближається свято, селянки заходяться коло свічок, свічка-саморобка в ярого воску, кажуть, угодніша богові; воскову свічку засвічують на Страсть, нею роблять хрести на одвірках, на вікнах, на сволоці; страсна свічка забезпечує худобу проти нечистої сили; її становлять у хліві, щоб відьма не мала приступу до корови.
  > <sub>// [Шульгина Л., «Пасічництво», 1925](https://www.nibu.kyiv.ua/elfond/shulgyna_pasichnyctvo/shulgyna_pasichnyctvo.pdf#page=61).</sub>

  > Саморобка, -ки, ж. Самодѣльная вещь.
  > <sub>// [Борис Грінченко, «Словарь української мови», 1909](https://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=49291&page=1066).</sub>
- Рукотвір — 1970:

  > Давно йде про нього добра слава: і килими, і вишивки бехівчан, мабуть, не мають собі рівних на Поліссі, бо в самих рукотворах відбита суть цього поетичного краю.
  > <sub>// Василь Скуратівський, «Село славне килимами» (у «Народна творчість та етнографія», 1970).</sub>

Складається враження (можливо, помилкове, бо не факт, що ці трапляння справді перші, та й загалом мої висновки доволі слабо обґрунтовані), що:

- *Саморобка* найстаріше. Утім це слово означає будь-що зроблене самотужки, необов'язково на простому рівні і, тим більше, дитячими руками.
- *Поробка* новіше. Цілком можливо, це калька з російського *поделка*. Але, зрештою, калькування — це просто один зі способів словотворення (зловживати ним не варто, але й демонізувати теж).
- *Рукотвір* здається найновішим. Утім, не виключаю, що воно вживалося й раніше, просто доволі рідко (можливо, у якомусь поетичному контексті чи високому стилі), і через це важко знайти трапляння.

Comment: "Поробку" я б не вживала, бо перша асоціація йде з "пороблено" :)

Comment: @Kreiri, є таке :).